# Google play, verification buyed application

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

Is there any way to verify purchase of application (not a in-app billing) using google play api?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **NO official** APIs of Google Play to consume data but you can try some ***Unofficial*** like

https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Answer (score 0):

From within the app you can use the LVL Licensing Verification Library:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html#LVL